# how do i stop the if statement from repeating?

Tags: arduino

This is for my spotwelder im building but it keeps pulsating the relay
the if statement is repeating infinetly and i cant figure out why.

I have tried an else statement and i have tried removing the delay. Please help.

so i am supposed to press the button once and it is supposed to trigger the relay for the amount of time of the pot then stop. right now it dosent it keeps repeating and triggering the relay every second

```
//spotwelder program
// created by Bradin
int buttonState = 0;
int potPin = A5;
int potVal;

int pinOut = 7;

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  pinMode(2, INPUT);
  pinMode(pinOut, OUTPUT);

  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {

  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  buttonState = digitalRead(2);
  potVal = analogRead(potPin);
  potVal = map(potVal, 0 , 1023, 10, 500);
  Serial.println(potVal);

  if (buttonState == HIGH) {
    digitalWrite(pinOut,HIGH);
    delay(potVal);
    digitalWrite(pinOut,LOW);
    delay(1000);
  } 
}
```

Comment: The if statement is repeating because it is in the loop function and the loop function gets repeated constantly, hence the name.  Right now your code says if the button is high to write the output pin high wait a while low wait a second and then repeat the whole process starting with checking the button again.  As long as you hold the button it will repeat the pulse.  If that isn't what you want then perhaps you can describe what you actually want and someone can help you figure out how to write it.

Comment: Did you connect a pulldown resistor to the button?

Answer (score 0):

Implement a state variable and a timer and it should work as you want:

```
 bool relayIsOn = false;
 unsigned long potVal;
 unsigned long startTime = 0;
```

and replace

```
void loop() {

  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  buttonState = digitalRead(2);

  if (buttonState == HIGH && !relayIsOn) {
     potVal = analogRead(potPin);
     potVal = map(potVal, 0 , 1023, 10, 500);
     Serial.println(potVal);
     relayIsOn = true;
     digitalWrite(pinOut, HIGH);
     startTime = millis();
   }
   if (millis() - startTime > potVal && relayIsOn) {  // Time is up
    relayIsOn = false;
    potVal = 0;
    digitalWrite(pinOut, Low);
   }
 }
```

This code is none blocking and reads the pot value the moment you press the button, if you wnat that to be different place the potRead/potmap before the first if, then you can influence the relay time during relay on.